# How do I delay an audio clip in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just started programming in Unity and what I'd like to do is to delay an audio clip to play by 5 seconds after the game starts.

I've searched online and found this code here, but when I execute it there is no sound.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WizardVoice : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioSource myAudio;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        StartCoroutine(PlaySoundAfterDelay(myAudio, 300.0f));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator PlaySoundAfterDelay(AudioSource audioSource, float delay)
    {
        if (audioSource == null)
            yield break;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        audioSource.Play();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to find out what I did wrong, but not having any luck.  Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Replace `if (audioSource == null)
            yield break;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        audioSource.Play();` with `if (audioSource == null){
           Debug.Log("Null");
            yield break;}else{
            Debug.Log("Not Null");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        audioSource.Play();}` then let me know what it says in the console tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It says: Not Null
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<PlaySoundAfterDelay>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Voices/WizardVoice.cs:20)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
WizardVoice:Start() (at Assets/Voices/WizardVoice.cs:9)
But it did not play the audio.

Comment: That's weird. What unity Version? Also try to open the audio in another program to make sure that it plays. It is music or just a short sound effect?

Comment: It's just a short voice over clip.  I know it works, because it will play if I check "Play On Awake" and it will also work if I type in the scripts "Start" event "myAudio.Play();"  I am using the beta version, 5.4 Beta 22 I think.  If you can think of anything else let me know!  Thank you!

Comment: I've got it.  Thank you!  It was in seconds.  So 5f = five seconds.  I overlooked that, sorry.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Nice. Feel free to mark my answer if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change `300.0f` to `5000f` because `300.0f` is 300 milliseconds and not 5 seconds. `1000f` = `1` second. Use `5000f` for `5`  seconds.That's how `WaitForSeconds();` work.